# How do I keep the current tab active with Tailwind CSS after a page reload?

Tags: tabs, tailwind-css

I'm currently using tabs from the Midone component with Tailwind CSS and want to select the same tab after a user has posted data and the page reloads.

How is this done?

My current call to init the tabs looks like this:

```html
<div class="mt-10 w-full box">
    <div class="p-2">
        <ul class="nav nav-link-tabs" role="tablist" id="myTab">
            <li id="tab-products" class="nav-item flex-1" role="presentation">
                <button class="nav-link w-full py-2 active"
                        data-tw-toggle="pill"
                        data-tw-target="#tab-products"
                        type="button"
                        role="tab" aria-controls="example-tab-3" aria-selected="true"><i class="fa-solid fa-boxes-stacked h-4 w-4 mr-2"></i>Produk
                </button>
            </li>
            <li id="tab-stores" class="nav-item flex-1" role="presentation">
                <button class="nav-link w-full py-2"
                        data-tw-toggle="pill"
                        data-tw-target="#tab-stores"
                        type="button"
                        role="tab" aria-controls="example-tab-4" aria-selected="false"><i class="fa-solid fa-store h-4 w-4 mr-2"></i>Lapak
                </button>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content mt-5">
            <div id="tab-products" class="tab-pane leading-relaxed active" role="tabpanel"
                 aria-labelledby="example-3-tab">
                <div class="overflow-x-auto">
                    tab 1
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="tab-stores" class="tab-pane leading-relaxed" role="tabpanel"
                 aria-labelledby="example-3-tab">
                <div class="overflow-x-auto">
                    tab 2
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is the documentation:

> Methods
> Get or Create Instance
> Static method which allows you to get the tab instance associated with a DOM element, or create a new one in case it wasn’t initialized.
>
> ```
> const myTab = tailwind.Tab.getOrCreateInstance(document.querySelector("#myTab"));
> const myTab = tailwind.Tab.getOrCreateInstance(document.querySelector("#myTab"));
> ```
>
> Get Instance
> Static method which allows you to get the tab instance associated with a DOM element.
>
> ```
> const myTab = tailwind.Tab.getInstance(document.querySelector("#myTab"));
> const myTab = tailwind.Tab.getInstance(document.querySelector("#myTab"));
> ```
>
> Show
> Manually opens a tab. Returns to the caller before the tab has actually been shown (i.e. before the `shown.tw.tab` event occurs).
>
> ```
> myTab.show();
> myTab.show();
> ```
>
> Events
> Midone’s tab class exposes a few events for hooking into tab functionality. All tab events are fired at the tab itself (i.e. at the `<div class="nav">`).
>
> Event type    - Description
>
> - `show.tw.tab`   - This event fires immediately when the show instance method is called.
> - `hide.tw.tab`   - This event is fired immediately when the hide instance method has been called.
>
> ```
> const myTabEl = document.getElementById('myTab')
> myTabEl.addEventListener('hidden.tw.tab', function(event) { //
> ```